# Netezza, Is there a way to replace a character by multiple characters?

Tags: replace, translate, netezza

I need to replace a character by multiple characters, i tried using **Translate**, but it just replace one by one according to the sequence defined in my case i need something like this

```
function( axbxc, "x", "yz") = ayzbyzc
```

if I use 
`translate( axbxc, "x", "yz")` i get `aybyc`

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks
Camilo

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is *replace* function

```
select replace( 'axbxc', 'x', 'yz')
```